# Ассерт для CRTP

Tags: c++, qt

Использую [**CRTP**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). В коде это выглядит так:

```
template<class T>
class Base{
    //...
};
class Derived : public Base<Derived>{
    //...    
};
```

Начали появляться copy/paste ошибки:

```
class Foo : public Base<Foo>{
    //...    
};
class Bar : public Base<Foo>{   //Ой
    //...    
};
```

Решил написать ассерт, который бы это дело проверял.

Придумал такой вариант:

```
template<class T>
class Base{
protected:
    typedef T TemplateType;
    typedef Base<T> BaseType;
    //...
};
class Derived : public Base<Derived>{
public:
    Derived(){
        Q_ASSERT(typeid(*this) == typeid(Base::TemplateType));
    }
    //...    
};
```

Но какой-то он неказистый. Работает на этапе выполнения, требует наличия каких-то непонятных тайпдефов.

И вот я здесь. Как написать такой ассерт используя C++03 и Qt? И чтобы его при этом было не стыдно людям показать.

Comment: а написать макрос вида `#define CRTP_CLASS(cl) class cl : public Base<cl>` ?

Comment: @KoVadim, тоже вариант. Только добавление к этому классу еще одного родителя будет выглядеть немного странно. `CRTP_CLASS(Foo), QObject{};`

Comment: Есть vardiac macros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой вариант:

```
template<typename D, typename B>
class IsDerivedFrom
{
    class No {};
    class Yes { No no[2]; };
    static Yes Test(B*);
    static No  Test(...);
public:
    enum { Is = sizeof(Test(static_cast<D*>(0)))==sizeof(Yes) };
};

template<typename T>
class Base
{
};

class D1: public Base<D1>
{
public:
    D1(){
        cout << IsDerivedFrom<D1,Base<D1> >::Is << endl;
    }
};

class D2: public Base<int>
{
public:
    D2() {
        cout << IsDerivedFrom<D2,Base<D2> >::Is << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;
}
```

Ну, понятно, что можно использовать `IsDerivedFrom<D,Base<D> >::Is` прямо во время компиляции.

Условие C++03 выполнено - Open Watcom успешно справился с компиляцией.

**Update** Решение 2. Не даст скомпилировать наследника от другого `Base<>`, copy-paste отработает - имени текущего класса в нем нет :). Увы, один `typedef` все же потребовался.

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{
    typedef T base;
};

template<typename T>
class IsDerivedFromBase
{
    static void Constraints(T*p)
    {
        Base<T>*b = p;
    }
public:
    IsDerivedFromBase() { void(*p)(T*) = Constraints; }
};


class D1: public Base<D1>
{
public:
    D1(){
        IsDerivedFromBase<Base::base>id;
    }
};

class D2: public Base<int>
{
public:
    D2() {
        IsDerivedFromBase<Base::base>id;
    }
};


int main()
{
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;
}
```

**Update 2** Пробуйте теперь:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class IsSame
{
public:
    enum { value = 0 };
};

template<typename T>
class IsSame<T,T>
{
public:
    enum { value = 1 };
};


template<typename T>
class Base
{
    typedef T base;
};

template<typename T>
class IsDerivedFromBaseThis
{
    static void Constraints(T*p)
    {
        Base<T>*b = p;
    }
public:
    template<typename U>
    IsDerivedFromBaseThis(U*) {
        int x[IsSame<T,U>::value];
        void(*p)(T*) = Constraints;
    }
};


class D1: public Base<D1>
{
public:
    D1(){
        IsDerivedFromBaseThis<Base::base>id(this);
    }
};

class D2: public Base<D1>
{
public:
    D2() {
        IsDerivedFromBaseThis<Base::base>id(this);
    }
};


int main()
{
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;
}
```

Comment: Спасбо за ответ. Но теперь у меня в копипасте будет `class Bar : public Base<Foo>{Bar(){IsDerivedFrom<Foo,Base<Foo>();}};` :D

Comment: Я думал в сторону protected функции `template<class T> void check(const T*)`. Чтобы при вызове `check(this)` она выводила тип текущего класса. А внутри уже выполнялась проверка

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Ну, как минимум можно чуть облегчить - `template<typename D>
class IsDerivedFrom
{
...    static Yes Test(Base<D>*);` до `IsDerivedFrom<D1>::Is`...

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Держите :) Работает, имя самого класса в себе не несет... Правда, один typedef все же понадобился.

Comment: [Я сломал](http://cpp.sh/8z4s7))) Пришлось немного поправить, но фундаментально я ничего не менял. Код компилируется не смотря на `class D2: public Base<D2>`

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Жестоко :)

Comment: Я придумал [такое решение](http://cpp.sh/6qt3g). Еще бы придумать как избавиться от функции `check`

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Смотрите третий вариант... Но, похоже, мы думали в одном направлении...